# facebook callback url for page webhook subscription

Tags: facebook

I am trying to connect my localhost server to facebook bot for testing by using ngrok.

I tried ngrok to connect my localhost to Facebook webhook subscription.
facebook show the following error : The url https://e431-125-99-185-146.in.ngrok.io/webhooks/facebook/webhook has been identified as malicious and/or abusive.

Comment: They either blocked your specific ngrok URL - or perhaps the whole service, if it caused too much issues with abuse.

Comment: tried with different ngrok url too. and just learning to make facebook bot with the help of rasa.